# Animated Text in Flutter , dart add curves in text style

Tags: android, flutter, dart

How to add `curves.bounceOut` in text animation;

```
Container(child:Text("hello"));
```

Comment: Can you include a gif what are you trying to archive

Answer (score 1):

you can define your own animation and controller and tweak it as you like
one way to do it
add  `with TickerProviderStateMixin` to your class
example :

```
class homeState extends State<home> with TickerProviderStat
```

then in your class define :

```
late AnimationController controller;
late Animation<double> animation
```

;

after that in the init state of your class you can use

```
controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 20),  // duration of the animation you want 
      vsync: this,
    );
animation = CurvedAnimation(parent: controller /* the controller we defined above */ , curve: Curves.bounceOut /* the curve of the animation you want */ );
// use
 controller.repeat(); //if you want the animation to loop
```

then use it with your  container
if you want to know more here is the flutter documentation [link](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/animations)
hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`animated_text_kit`](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_text_kit) [`Wavy`](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_text_kit#wavy) animation

Example from doc

```dart
return DefaultTextStyle(
  style: const TextStyle(
    fontSize: 20.0,
  ),
  child: AnimatedTextKit(
    animatedTexts: [
      WavyAnimatedText('Hello World'),
      WavyAnimatedText('Look at the waves'),
    ],
    isRepeatingAnimation: true,
    onTap: () {
      print("Tap Event");
    },
  ),
);
```

You can find more animation on package

Answer (score 0):

Please Use this code for animation text;
follow this code if it helpfull;

### Create Variables

```
    late AnimationController controller;
    late Animation<double> animation;
    int hrs = 0;
    int minute = 0;
    int second = 0;
    double opacity = 0.1;
    int duration = 0;
    double hp = 0.0;
    double mp = 0.0;
    double sp = 0.0;
```

### Create Function and add within initState() function;

```
    timer() async {
    DateTime date = DateTime.now();
    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () {
      setState(() {
        duration = 900;
        sp = 10;
        date = DateTime.now();
        second = date.second;
        hrs = date.hour;
        minute = date.minute;
        var inputFormat = DateFormat('HH');
        var inputDate = inputFormat.parse(hrs.toString());
        var outputFormat = DateFormat('hh');
        hrs = int.parse(outputFormat.format(inputDate).toString());
        if (second == 0) {
          mp = 10;
        } else if (minute == 0) {
          hp = 10;
        }
        timer();
      });
    });
    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 900), () {
      setState(() {
        sp = 0;
        mp = 0;
        hp = 0;
        duration = 0;
      });
    });
  }
```

### Create a Widget

```
    Widget animatedText(String text, double animatedPadding) {
    return TweenAnimationBuilder(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      curve: Curves.bounceIn,
      tween: IntTween(begin: 0, end: 1),
      builder: (context, int val, child) {
        if (val != 1 && opacity < 1.0) {
          opacity = opacity + 0.1;
        } else if (opacity > 1.0 || opacity == 1.0) {
          opacity = 1.0;
        }
        return Opacity(
          opacity: opacity >= 0.0 && opacity <= 1.0 ? opacity : 0,
          child: AnimatedPadding(
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: duration),
              curve: Curves.bounceOut,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: animatedPadding),
              child: child),
        );
      },
      child: Text(
        text,
        style: const TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 24.0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

### add animatedText in Container ;

```
    Container(alignment: Alignment.center,
          height: Sizes.height * 0.05,
          width: Sizes.width * 0.1,
          child: animatedText(second.toString(), sp)),
```